# Is there any way to stream music in the background with Ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Android app using Ionic for music streaming, like a personal Spotify. I can easily play an audio file using Streaming Media plugin, but it seems that this plugin was made for video purposes, because it always brings the player to the front in fullscreen, so you can't navigate through the app while the music is playing, you also can't lock your screen or the playback is stopped.

Is there any way to stream music in the background? Like when I tap the song I want to play, it just starts playing without bringing in another screen? (like you can easily do in AndroidStudio with MediaPlayer). I've search it anywhere for the past week and I just can't find any solution.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/music-controls/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized Background-Audio in my ionic2/3 Project with

```
cordova-plugin-media 3.0.1 "Media"
cordova-plugin-music-controls 2.1.4 "MusicControls"
```

and to workaround some issues on ios I need to add this plugin also

```
nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio 1.0.1 "background-audio"
```

Comment: for streaming or local files? isn't Media only for local files?

Comment: it could be that media is a dependency for MusicControls.. I stream our campus web radio station on ios and android. cordova-plugin-music-controls give you lockscreen controls for your music and background-audio fixed some 'ios not playing when the app is in background' issues

Comment: ok, something was wrong with my build. I made a new project and tried again with Media and now it's working as intended. thank you.